# Image blank when handling image from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I have 2 web api´s. One that connects to the DB and get the data (webapi 2). And another that just handle this data and send to the Client side (webapi 1).
The problem is that when is a string, the handle Works. But with the image is not working. I am getting the general internal server error 500.
If i call just the WebApi 2, I get the image. If I call the WebApi 1 that calls the webapi 2, the image is blank.

My Web Api Handler:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Foto")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetFoto(string suspid, string pk)
{
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    };

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        //QUANDO TESTAR NO SERVIDOR

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.111.56.1:1762/");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("image/jpeg"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Nomes/Foto?suspid="+suspid+"&pk="+pk+"");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var data = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
            response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The Web Api that connects to the DB:

I am hiding the connect string and other stuff that doesn't matter.

```
cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = -1;
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
byte[] imgBytes = null;

if (reader.Read())
{
    // Fetch the LONG RAW
    OracleBinary imgBinary = reader.GetOracleBinary(0);
    // Get the bytes from the binary obj
    imgBytes = imgBinary.IsNull ? null : imgBinary.Value;

}
connection.Close();
connection.Dispose();

try
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new MemoryStream(imgBytes);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");

    return result;
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Gone);
}
```

Comment: have your tried:  a) attaching a debugger and tracing the error?  b) adding logging to your handler?  c) wrapping your handler in a try/catch?  Any of those would help you track down the specific cause of the error.

Comment: @Jason i tried the a) and the c) . In the a) i don´t have a error...when i get the HttpResponseMessage response, comes normally but i have a "internal server error" code 500. With try catch, doesnt have a error on the try. How i add a logging to a handler ?

Comment: google "webapi logging".  Although a 500 probably logs something to the IIS log by default

Comment: @Jason i am a newbie ! So, i am trying but not success :(

Comment: @Jason strange is that the HttpResponseMessage for the webapi 2 is OK and have the contente normally... but when i receive this on webapi 1, it comes with status false with error.